# Bootstrap navbar not working below an image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

```
</head>
<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="test">
      <%= image_tag("img_mountains_wide.jpg", :style => "width:100%") %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="header">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Homepage", root_path %></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              About <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "test1", test_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "test2", test2_path %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
              <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
              <% if logged_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
              <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="main-body">
  <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the current form, the links in the navbar don't work (can not even click on them). There are two ways how I can make this work again: I can remove the image (navbar is then on the top of the page and works fine) or I can change

header class="navbar navbar-inverse"

into

header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse"

(navbar is then above the image on the top of the page and works fine again). How can I make the navbar work also below the image? The end result is supposed to be a slideshow right above the navbar (I simply assume that once I fix the image problem, the navbar will also work below a slideshow.)

Answer (score 0):

You had some problem in your mar-up. `class="navbar navbar-inverse"` goes with nav tag not header tag. remove the header tag and use it with the `<nav>` tag it will work fine.

**Working example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="test">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" style = "width:100%;">
    </div>

  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="header">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="www.google.com">home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="https://www.google.co.in" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              About <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="www.google.com">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="www.google.com">test2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
              <li><a href="www.google.com">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="www.google.com">login</a></li>
             
          </ul>
      
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="main-body">
</div>

</body>
```

Hope this helps!